# Ошибка при инициализации SSLConnectionSocketFactory при создании HttpClient. Ошибка NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

Tags: ssl, https, java-8, httpclient, apache-httpclient

Ошибка при инициализации  SSLConnectionSocketFactory.

При инициализации

```
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = 
      HttpClients.custom().setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
```

Получаю ошибку

```
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE

at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<clinit>(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:146)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:958)
at ru.ofd.rc.service.PackageSenderService.sendRawMessage(PackageSenderService.java:124)
at ru.ofd.rc.service.SendReceiptService.sendExternalReceipts(SendReceiptService.java:79)
at ru.ofd.rc.service.SendReceiptService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3746432f.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:667)
at ru.ofd.rc.service.SendReceiptService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$77de6ae4.sendExternalReceipts(<generated>)
at ru.ofd.rc.test.tests.debug.ReceiptsSendingTest.sendReceiptToHub(ReceiptsSendingTest.java:81)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Зависимости в maven

```
  ` <!-- Httpclient-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.4</version>
    </dependency>`
```

Проблемы в самой библиотеке, в этом месте

```
    @Deprecated
    public static final X509HostnameVerifier ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER
    = AllowAllHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;
```

Но как от нее избавиться не понимаю.
Пробовал устанавливать и более новые и более старые версии, ничего не помогло.
Пробовал удалить ~/.m2/ директорию и заново установить все зависимости.
Не понимаю в чем причина и как избавить от этой ошибки.

Comment: На английском stackoverflow есть схожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22330848/1597497 Посмотрите, может поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение своей проблемы.
У меня была java 1.8_221 и там эта ошибка появлялась.
Я загрузил более раннюю версию java 1.8_181 
и там этой проблемы не было.
Это помогло решить мою проблему.